# CSV with a subset of columns

Tags: python, csv

Write a function named "filter_columns" that takes a string as a parameter representing the name of a CSV file with 5 columns in the format "string,int,int,int,int" and writes a file named "distant.csv" containing only the first and fifth columns from the input file.

```
import csv
def filter_columns(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as rf:
        reader = csv.reader(rf)
        with open('distant.csv', 'w') as wf:
            writer = csv.writer(wf)
            for item in reader:
                writer.writerow(item[0] + str(int(item[4])))
```

When inputting in the file items.csv

```
bed,7,22,137,157
defender,14,58,185,61
```

I should get

```
bed,157
defender,61
```

But, I am getting

```
b,e,d,1,5,7
d,e,f,e,n,d,e,r,6,1
```

How do I remove the unwanted commas?

Comment: writer.writerow([item[0],item[-1]])  , this should do.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html, csvwrite.writerow takes an iterable as argument.

When you write `item[0]+str(int(item[4]))`, you are producing a string, which is a list of characters. Hence the output is like `d,e,f,e,n,d,e,r,6,1`.

I might want to try:

```
import csv
def filter_columns(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as rf:
        reader = csv.reader(rf)
        with open('distant.csv', 'w') as wf:
            writer = csv.writer(wf)
            for item in reader:
                print(item)
                writer.writerow([item[0]]+[str(int(item[4]))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `writerow`.

```
writer.writerow([item[0]]+[item[4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the string `item[0] + str(int(item[4]))` to `writer.writerow`. For example, for the first row you're passing `"bed157"`, when `writer.writerow` expects an iterable (e.g. a list) it converts the string you are passing to ["b", "e", "d", "1", "5", "7"].

You need to pass a list/tuple:

```
import csv

def filter_columns(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as rf:
        reader = csv.reader(rf)
        with open('distant.csv', 'w') as wf:
            writer = csv.writer(wf)
            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow([row[0], str(row[4])])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import csv
def filter_columns (x):
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        with open ('museum.csv', 'w') as g:
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            for line in reader:
                writer.writerow((line[0], str(line[2])))
```